# ASP.NET/jQuery: Reading jQuery file over HTTPS causing Access is Denied

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net, internet-explorer-7

We have a site that is public facing, let's say it's http://www.example.com. When the SSL is implemented, https://www.example.com, I can no longer access the jQuery 1.4.3 file on my own server. Furthermore, after a tweak to the security setting, I was able to get past the 'Access is Denied' error, but the first call was null.

I understand there is a problem with different protocols actually being within the scope of the cross-domain problem? Is that true? And if so, will this now require JSONP?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery.jstree.min.js") %>"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js") %>"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery.cookie.min.js") %>"></script>
```

Comment: Here's my links. Amazingly, I have the same exact links for the CSS files and they work. And the Javascript files actually resolve with HTTPS://

Comment: Unfortunately, I am trying to debug the site without any access to it. I'm only allowed to use my development environment. We added SSL certificate to the IIS Server this morning, and we can now replicate it internally as well, so we know it's the HTTPS protocol

Comment: If they don't let you use Firebug, you should find a better job.  You're missing out on the _ultimate_ web dev tool; the one that inspired everything else.

Comment: I personally use it daily. I may need to try to get access to the site that's having trouble.

Comment: Do they offer VPN access? Can you use Firefox Portable or connect a personal laptop to their network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an HTTPS site, you should try to load all resources, including script files, from HTTPS URLs.

If you load a single Javascript file (or JSONP API) from a non-HTTPS URL, you've defeated the purpose of HTTPS, since an attacker can intercept that file and inject a Javascript password-stealer or session hijacker.

Also note that you cannot send AJAX requests from HTTPS URLs to non-HTTPS URLs or vice-versa.

Comment: We are using ResolveClientUrl to grab each javascript file, including the jQuery file.

Comment: That should work fine.  What error do you get? What's the generated HTML?  Do you reference any scripts from other domains?

Comment: Actually, I was getting an error on line 127 of the jQuery file, e.username?x.open(n,e.url,e.async,e.username,e.password)

From what I’ve read, this is supposedly a cross domain error. The problem is that I’ve searched through my code and everything references the current domain.

Comment: @jlrolin: You're probably sending an AJAX request to a hard-coded non-HTTPS URL.  Can you look at the error's stack trace and find the calling code? Even without Firebug, you can see that in an IE debugger (VS or IE8 Dev Tools)

Comment: No, I'm not. I've checked everywhere.

Comment: Well, that's the explanation for the error.  What's up the call stack?

Comment: Well, I have to get access to look at the call stack. Very limiting I know, I'll work on that for now.

Comment: The problem was that we had a Url Resolve function that didn't account for the https. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Different protocols are treated as different servers, quite correctly.

If the same file is available at the same path on each server, you can use a protocol-relative URL:

```
<script src="//www.example.com/js/jquery.1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can also use a normal relative URL.

Comment: @SLaks A good point, presuming that there's no mucking about with `base`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter, URLs come back as HTTPS